# Visual studio 2017 line breaks in cshtml

Tags: visual-studio, razor, intellisense

I have some annoying situation:

When I'm typing code and opening braces Visual studio insert double line break. Like this:

```
function a(){


}
```

I need:

```
function a(){

}
```

Help me please find proper setting.

Visual Studio 2017 > CSHTML > javascript block.
In .js files all works fine.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried custom the VS setting? In my VS 2017 15.3.3 version, I followed your description and found there only have one line, please check this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgyqWhTj9w88mAPG_ 1. please go to Help-About Microsoft Visual Studio, if the version is not the 15.3.3, re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator and click ‘Update’ to upgrade, 2. go to Tools-Import and Export settings>Reset all settings, backup the current setting and restore to the ‘General’ 3. Run the command: devenv /safemode to check if the installed extensions affect it.

Comment: Thanks. Tried already. Have new details: project type: .net core 1.1 / .net core 2.0 (with .net framework web app all works fine). VS 15.3.3 (lastest)

Answer (score 0):

After confirmed with the ASP.NET Core web application, I can reproduced it and I have already reported this issue to the VS Product Team, please check this: [VS 2017(15.3.3): in the Asp.NET Core Web application>*.cshtml>JS block and define the function, press Enter key inside the opening braces will get double new lines](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110388/vs-20171533-in-the-aspnet-core-web-applicationcsht.html) and you can add your own comment, let us waiting for the response comes from the VS Product Team, thanks.
[image]